# Laravel Eloquent "WHERE NOT IN"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having trouble to write query in `laravel eloquent ORM`.

my query is

```
SELECT book_name,dt_of_pub,pub_lang,no_page,book_price  
FROM book_mast        
WHERE book_price NOT IN (100,200);
```

Now I want to convert this query into laravel eloquent.

Answer (score 468, accepted):

Query Builder:

```
DB::table(..)->select(..)->whereNotIn('book_price', [100,200])->get();
```

Eloquent:

```
SomeModel::select(..)->whereNotIn('book_price', [100,200])->get();
```

Comment: `select` can be replaced with an array in `get`.

Comment: @Marwelln, yes, but it's won't be working with complex queries. E.g. with addSelect method.

Answer (score 39):

You can use **WhereNotIn** in following way also:

```
ModelName::whereNotIn('book_price', [100,200])->get(['field_name1','field_name2']);
```

This will return collection of **Record** with specific fields

Answer (score 18):

I had problems making a sub query until I added the method `->toArray()` to the result, I hope it helps more than one since I had a good time looking for the solution.

**Example**

```
DB::table('user')                 
  ->select('id','name')
  ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('curses')->select('id_user')->where('id_user', '=', $id)->get()->toArray())
  ->get();
```

Comment: ->pluck('id_user') instead of ->toArray() works for me

Comment: This approach is not optimized, a sub query is better. ```DB::table('curses')->select('id_user')->where('id_user', '=', $id)->get()->toArray() ``` is performing a full DB query and retrieving results. There's 2 SQL query calls to the database in this case. Suggest to use
```->whereNotIn('id', function($q){ $q->table('curses')->select('id_user')->where('id_user', '=', $id); })``` instead.

Answer (score 12):

Query Builder:

```
    DB::table('book_mast')
->select('book_name','dt_of_pub','pub_lang','no_page','book_price')
    ->whereNotIn('book_price', [100,200])->get();
```

Eloquent:

```
BookMast::select('book_name','dt_of_pub','pub_lang','no_page','book_price')
->whereNotIn('book_price', [100,200])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is more or less a duplicate of the existing answers.

Comment: yes, but that is how whereNotIn is done in laravel. Anyways thanks for comment.

Answer (score 5):

The dynamic way of implement whereNotIn:

```
 $users = User::where('status',0)->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
                $data[] = $user->id;
            }
    $available = User::orderBy('name', 'DEC')->whereNotIn('id', $data)->get();
```

Comment: Your example is over complex. `User::orderBy('name', 'DESC')->where('status', '!=',0)->get()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this example for dynamically calling the **Where NOT IN**

```
$user = User::where('company_id', '=', 1)->select('id)->get()->toArray();

$otherCompany = User::whereNotIn('id', $user)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `WhereNotIn` in the following way:

```
$category=DB::table('category')
          ->whereNotIn('category_id',[14 ,15])
          ->get();`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do following.

```
DB::table('book_mast') 
->selectRaw('book_name,dt_of_pub,pub_lang,no_page,book_price')  
->whereNotIn('book_price',[100,200]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my working variant for Laravel 7

```
DB::table('user')                 
  ->select('id','name')
  ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('curses')->where('id_user', $id)->pluck('id_user')->toArray())
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Its simply means that you have an array of values and you want record except that values/records.*

*you can simply pass a array into whereNotIn() laravel function.*

**With query builder**

```
$users = DB::table('applications')
                    ->whereNotIn('id', [1,3,5]) 
                    ->get(); //will return without applications which contain this id's
```

**With eloquent.**

```
$result = ModelClassName::select('your_column_name')->whereNotIn('your_column_name', ['satatus1', 'satatus2']); //return without application which contain this status.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$created_po = array();
     $challan = modelname::where('fieldname','!=', 0)->get();
     // dd($challan);
     foreach ($challan as $rec){
         $created_po[] = array_push($created_po,$rec->fieldname);
     }
     $data = modelname::whereNotIn('fieldname',$created_po)->orderBy('fieldname','desc')->with('modelfunction')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**or try pluck** in laravel
here

```
DB::table('user')                 
          ->select('id','name')
          ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('curses')->where('id_user', '=', $id)->pluck('user_id'))
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

YourModel::select('column_name')->whereNotIn('book_price', [100,200])->get();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).