# eloquent where not in query?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to build the following sql query with eloquent. The query gives me all records from table_a which are in the list of ids and do not appear in table_b.

```
select * from table_a 
where id in (1,2,3)
   and id not in 
      (select tablea_id from table_b 
       where tablea_id in (1,2,3))
```

So how do I do it in eloquent ? I want to avoid using a raw query.

```
//does not work
TableA::whereIn('id',$ids)
   ->whereNotIn('id', TableB::select('tabla_id')->whereIn($ids));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent "WHERE NOT IN"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849015/laravel-eloquent-where-not-in)

Comment: `whereNotIn` takes an array as second parameter... RTFM

Comment: @pc-shooter Not true, it takes a closure as well!

Comment: @lukasgeiter OOpps, so same for me (re)read th F* manual... Thx for pointig at!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To run a subquery you have to pass a closure:

```
TableA::whereIn('id',$ids)
      ->whereNotIn('id', function($q){
          $q->select('tabla_id')
            ->from('tableb');
            // more where conditions
      })
      ->get();
```

Comment: @pc-shooter Whoops thanks. Feel free to edit such obvious typos yourself next time ;)

Comment: Tought that I couldn't just edit one character in other users posts?

Comment: Ah I see... I'm over that rep limit so I forgot that for a second

Comment: It's fine like this, there would be a lot "just-code-formatting-or-one-two-chars-editing"