# or where query on model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to figure out why something is happening.

When a Model is created it is given a status parameter.  Initially the status is Awaiting Information, but it soon gets changed to Awaiting Acceptance.  I am trying to display models on my page only if their status has passed these two stages.  At the moment I have the following

```
$projects = Project::with('client')->where('status', '!=', 'Awaiting Information')->orWhere('status', '!=', 'Awaiting Acceptance')->get();
```

For some reason however, this returns a project that has the status Awaiting Information.  If I remove the orWhere part, then no projects are displayed as is expected.  It appears the orWhere is throwing  the query off.  I am looking to return all projects which do not have these statuses.

Am I missing something here in my clauses?

Thanks

Comment: Please prefer this answer, It's helpful for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849015/laravel-eloquent-where-not-in]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use whereNotIn method for your query:

```
$projects = Project::with('client')->whereNotIn('status', ['Awaiting Information', 'Awaiting Acceptance'])->get();
```