# How to use an array in where clause in MySQL query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I have an array $time_schedule_id= array(1,3,5). Now I want those data which are not matched with the given array ( $time_schedule_id= array(1,3,5) ) from $time_schedule_table.

```
DB::table('time_schedule_table')
select('*')
where('id','!=', ?)
```

How can I generate this query string to use with MySQL?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849015/laravel-eloquent-where-not-in

Comment: use whereNotIn from laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel `whereNotIn()` eloquent function

`DB::table('time_schedule_table')->select(*)->whereNotIn('id', [1,3,5])->get();`

Comment: @Mr.Developer......absolutely right