# Can we use whereIn clause with not equal

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to do following

```
Model::select('column')->whereIn('column','!=',array)->first();
```

So how can i achieve this. Any suggestions Thank you.

Comment: not if you put `,array)` in there (probably a syntax error as array is a keyword in PHP).  Well I don't use Laravel, but I can tell that probably wont do what you want.  Maybe it's just a typo in the question?

Comment: You can use `whereNotIn('column', $array)`. You can check out docs @ https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `whereIn` you can use `whereNotIn`.

Like this:

```
Model::select('column')->whereNotIn('column', array(1,2,3))->first();
```

Comment: If it's working, please accept as a right answer for other users to give help.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `whereNotIn('column', $array)`. See the [Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) documentation for more methods.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
Model::whereNotIn('id',[10,20])->select('id')->first();
```

Go through [Laravel Eloquent “WHERE NOT IN”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849015/laravel-eloquent-where-not-in)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
Model::select('column')->whereNotIn('column',array)->first();
```